# Get the value of current table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have multiple `<tr>` elements and I need to find the Id which corresponds to that object.
Basically when I click edit I need the selected ID to be alerted to the user.

[image]

```
    <tr>
        <td ><input type="hidden" name="pkAdminId" value="1076">1076</td>
        <td><a class="editCredential" class="openWindow" data-modal-id="existingCredential" data-credential-id="1076">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a class="delete">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ><input type="hidden" name="pkAdminId" value="1073">1073</td>
        <td><a class="editCredential" class="openWindow" data-modal-id="existingCredential" data-credential-id="1073">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a class="delete">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ><input type="hidden" name="pkAdminId" value="1074">1074</td>
        <td><a class="editCredential" class="openWindow" data-modal-id="existingCredential" data-credential-id="1074">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a class="delete">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ><input type="hidden" name="pkAdminId" value="1075">1075</td>
        <td><a class="editCredential" class="openWindow" data-modal-id="existingCredential" data-credential-id="1075">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a class="delete">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
```

The JQuery which I have tried only finds the value of the first table row which is 1076 in this case.

```
$('.existingCredential').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    var id = $('input[name="pkAdminId"]').val();
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: In future problems with HTML/CSS/JS code, please do not post server side code responsible for generating all that HTML/CSS/JS. This is of no use for HTML/CSS/JS experts. Instead, post the generated HTML/CSS/JS right away.

Comment: @BalusC I apologize, I will remember that for future questions! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `closest` along with element context `this` to traverse to parent tr and then find element in it:

```
$('.existingCredential').on('click', '.delete', function() {
 var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="pkAdminId"]').val();
 alert(id);
});
```